# WebGrease manifest definition mismatch when debugging a Kendo MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I get this error when I try to debugg my Kendo MVC app:

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

How can I solve this?

Comment: I found the cause of this error. yes, recently i have installed some file using nuget.. In ur webconfig file, just remove the following code..                                                                    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: When the system allows you to, you can post the solution as an answer and accept it later on.